# How to obtain the names of multiple attachments from an access form

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, attachment

I have created a basic form in access that contains an attachment field and a button that when clicked, opens up a window that allows the user to email the name of all the attachments that are uploaded to the form. I use:

```
Dim bodytext As String
bodytext = Me.Field1.FileName
DoCmd.SendObject acSendNoObject, stDocName, acFormatXLS, "person123@gmail.com", , , "mysubject", bodytext, True
```

I used `bodytext` as a string to hold the name of the attachment and it is able to pull out the current attachment that is displayed on the form. What would be a way to list off all the names of the attachment in that form. My end goal is to be able to send an email all the names of all the attachments.[Screenshot of the form.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4qO3U.jpg)

For example, if I uploaded three files: attachment1.txt, attachment2.txt, and attachment3.txt, I would like to send all three names in the email. Any help is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Attachments have a couple of Properties

[image: Attachment Properties]

```
Attachments.FileName
```

You could try a Query

```
"SELECT ID, {attachmentfieldname}.FileName FROM {TABLE}"
```

And Filter on the Record ID

```
" WHERE ID = 1"
```

(Note: Away from a computer, need to check this)

https://support.office.com/en-za/article/Attach-files-and-graphics-to-the-records-in-your-database-d40a09ad-a753-4a14-9161-7f15baad6dbd#bm4